# rems display but ems don't - why the difference?

Tags: css

I was playing around with [Ruandre's excellent codepen](http://codepen.io/ruandre/pen/howFi) of social media icons. [Here's](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVdoZv) my version.

I've honestly never used rems before (always ems within frameworks that define root font sizes). I can't understand why my anchor elements are sized 0px when I specify ems, and why it works for rems. Could someone explain what's going on here?

```
html {
  background: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.soc {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="soc">
<li><a>Icon</a></li>
<li><a>Icon</a></li>
<li><a>Icon</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your anchor font size is 0

Comment: You're supposed to be posting an MCVE (ie. enough code to reproduce the problem within the question itself).  This is not a Sass problem, either.

Comment: Updated with code and removed Sass tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font size of your anchor tag is 0 so any 'em' of 0 is 0 which is why you get no width or height.

Since rem is based on root element, you get a size. I verified the em thing with inspector, once you add a font size to the anchor instead of 0, you will see the icons

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVdgbo

I updated the `.soc` to have a font size of `10px`

Comment: Oh you're right. I completely missed the font size attribute there ... must be going blind. Thank you.